# How Create a CardView inside a recycleView?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I was developing an simple App, and in the main View I would like to show a list of a Cards, which display different information about the providers.

An example cuold be something like this:

[image]

So I would like to do is a RecycleView, made from CardView items, but when I try to implement this, I realize that I don't have any idea about what the method onBindViewHolder() do.

Another question would be how to create the recycle view based on the CardsView items.

Here it a part of my code:

MyAdapter.class

```
package com.example.apaados;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.cardview.widget.CardView;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    private String[] mDataset;

    // Provide a reference to the views for each data item
    // Complex data items may need more than one view per item, and
    // you provide access to all the views for a data item in a view holder
    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        // each data item is just a string in this case
        public CardView textView;
        public MyViewHolder(CardView v) {
            super(v);
            textView = v;
        }
    }

    // Provide a suitable constructor (depends on the kind of dataset)
    public MyAdapter(String[] myDataset) {
        mDataset = myDataset;
    }

    // Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public MyAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                     int viewType) {
        // create a new view
        CardView v = (CardView) LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.card_view_main_view, parent, false);

        MyViewHolder vh = new MyViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }

    // Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        // - get element from your dataset at this position
        // - replace the contents of the view with that element
        /****** I don't know what i have to do here.*************/
holder.itemView.
        

    }

    // Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDataset.length;
    }
}
```

recycleView.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainView">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycleView"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="174dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="152dp" >

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView

            <!--  HERE i WOULD LIKE TO RECOVER THE XML OF MY CARD VIEW -->
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"



    </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And this is my CardView xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp"
    >

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/cv"
        >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="16dp"
            >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/photo_card"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/txtTitulo_Card"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txtDescripcion_Card"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/txtDescripcion_Card"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/photo_card"
                android:layout_below="@+id/txtTitulo_Card"
                />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

If you know some example of the implementation of a CardView item insede of RecycleView, take thanks for advance!

Comment: This has no technical difference with any other recyclerview implementation. Just look for a basic recyclerview tutorial or the documentation and use a cardview for the viewholder (like you've already started doing)

Comment: OKey, that right, and which method should I invocate into the onBindViewHolder(), calling "holder.itemView........."

Comment: Each `RecyclerView` has an adapter and a `list_item` layout which is populated to show multiple times, in your case the `CardView`.  The `onBindViewHolder()` in your `Adapter` class populates your each CardView based on the position and data of the arraylist on that position and hence, it provides an argument `position` which is when combined with the view of that card `holder`, you create a list of `CardView` or any other `Layout`. So, declare your Views in `MyViewHolder` class, access them in `onBindViewHolder()` like `holder.textView` and set its values or `onClickListener()` on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to replace this code in the cardview file

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/cv"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="5dp">
```